# How to know when a Lottie animation is completed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, lottie

I have a fragment, here is the onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_added_to_cart_anim, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, mView);

    mAddedToCartAnimation.setAnimation("checked_done_.json");
    mAddedToCartAnimation.loop(false);
    mAddedToCartAnimation.playAnimation();

    // Remove fragment when the animation is finished.

    return mView;

}
```

I need to remove the fragment using `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();` when the [lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) animation has ended. If I understand correctly when the `isAnimating()` Lottie method returns false the animation has ended and since in my configuration the animation does not loop this is when I should remove the current fragment. But I can't just use an if statement since when it is executed the animation may still be going.

I need a way to remove the fragment when the Lottie animation ends, how do I do this?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
mAddedToCartAnimation.addAnimatorListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            Log.e("Animation:","start");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            Log.e("Animation:","end");
            //Your code for remove the fragment
            try {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                      .beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.toString();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            Log.e("Animation:","cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            Log.e("Animation:","repeat");
        }
    });
```

I hope this solve your problem :)

Comment: @Chefes : on First animation end , I tried running the second animation. but the second animation keep's looping after it completes its first round.  is there any other way in which the chain animations can be achieved?

Comment: Note: If you have made the visibility of the Lottie view as Invisible or gone, the animation listener won't be triggered

Comment: does this have equivalent code for angular?

Comment: I don't have experience with Lottie and Angular but maybe the "complete" callback can help you CC @Titus https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-lottie#api

Answer (score 25):

Kotlin Code for animation complete :

```
successAnimation.addAnimatorListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener{
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                //Add your code here for animation end
            }

            override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
            }

            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin , you can this way:

```
val lotWelcome=findViewById<LottieAnimationView>(R.id.lot_1) 
   
lotWelcome.addAnimatorListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
       override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator) {
           Log.e("Animation:", "start")
       }
   override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
       Log.e("Animation:", "end")
       //Ex: here the layout is removed!
       firstScreen.visibility= View.GONE
   }

   override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) {
       Log.e("Animation:", "cancel")
   }

   override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator) {
       Log.e("Animation:", "repeat")
   }

  })
```

By the way , you can see the original document here:
https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/android