# Android Xamarin: Detect Lottie Animation End

Tags: android, animation, xamarin, nuget, lottie

I want to inflate a Layout-File in my DialogFragment which only holds one LottieAnimationView

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
  android:id="@+id/animViewTest1"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  app:lottie_fileName="json_Saved.json"
  app:lottie_loop="false"
  app:lottie_autoPlay="false"
  />
```

I want the Fragment to show up, play the animation once, and automatically close, after the animation is finished.

I can access the AnimView

```
animView = view.FindViewById<LottieAnimationView>(Resource.Id.animViewTest1);
animView.PlayAnimation();
```

but i can't find a way to get to the `onAnimationEnd` Method or something similar.

I found this similar question: [How to know when lottie animation is completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180874/how-to-know-when-lottie-animation-is-completed/46181162#comment86256822_46181162)

But it does not helped me to make it work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use IAnimatorListener listener, just implement it by your class:

```
YourClass : IAnimatorListener
```

with all needed methods, one of them is what you're after:

```
public void OnAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
{
// your logic on animation end
}
```

and then assign your IAnimatorListener implementation as animator listener of your lottie view:

```
this.animationView.AddAnimatorListener(implementationOfIAnimatorListener);
```

You can find a full example on Lottie Xamarin github: https://github.com/martijn00/LottieXamarin/blob/develop/Samples/Native/Example.Droid/AnimationFragment.cs