# Hello everyone, I created an splash screen using Lottie animation and my problem is after the animation is completed, How do i change activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, native

**Here is my Lottie animation code:**

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ImageView logo,splashImg;
LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);
    splashImg = findViewById(R.id.img);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.Motto);
    lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.lottie);

    splashImg.animate().translationY(-2800).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);
    logo.animate().translationY(1850).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);
    textView.animate().translationY(1800).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);
    lottieAnimationView.animate().translationY(1800).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);



}
```

}

**And Now I want to go to another Activity, How do I do it??**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Handler` class for this purpose and then navigate to your second or new `Activity` subclass by using `Intent` like so. In short this code will navigate to the other activity by waiting for 2000 milliseconds or 2 seconds which can be customised. Maybe you can add set it according to when your animation is done by selecting the duration of largest among all

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   private void run(){
     Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, YourNewActivity.class)
     startActivity(intent)
   }

}, 2000)
```

Another clean approach would to be add an `AnimationListener` and as soon as the animation completes just fire an `Intent` to start the other `Activity`

You can find how to use `AnimationListener` specially for `Lottie` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181162/9722336)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code:

```
mAddedToCartAnimation.addAnimatorListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        Log.e("Animation:","start");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this,NewActivity.class));

        //Your code for remove the fragment
        try {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                  .beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        Log.e("Animation:","cancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        Log.e("Animation:","repeat");
    }
});
```